# Python Two values that are the same aren't resulting true in an if statement

Tags: python

In the function part2 I have the values being checked against each other to see if they are the same, and I even printed them out to see but the if statement isn't being executed even though they are! I cant figure out why this is happening

http://pastebin.com/kt19wpcg

Comment: which if statement are you talking about?? narrow it down and paste the relevant code here

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is that `splitLine = data[i].split("eats")` does not strip out the trailing spaces, meaning that you will get an element like `"Bird "` instead of `"Bird"`. When you print the two, you can't see the difference, but when Python compares them, they are two different strings. This looks like an assignment, so I would suggest looking into how to remove spaces after splitting a string.

Answer (score 1):

After you split the string, please use `.strip()` on the pieces. It'll remove all leading and lagging spaces.